# Web Scraping with selenium - List is out of index - issue

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I need a support to fix the below code. I have created this python code to do some web scraping using finq.com. Using selenium, it automates the login process and after that, i do require to do this web scraping of a particular table. This is a stock update. daily figures. And the below code runs with the issue "List out of index" can you please help me to sort this out?

The selenium automation is working perfectly.

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium import webdriver
# finq credentials
username = "xxxxxx@gmail.com"
password = "xxxxxxxxx"
# initialize the Chrome driver
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Users\snyder\seaborn-data\chromedriver.exe')
driver.maximize_window()
driver.implicitly_wait(5)
driver.get("https://www.finq.com/en/login")
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "iframe[id='login']")))
# find username/email field and send the username itself to the input field
driver.find_element_by_id("login_username").send_keys(username)
# find password input field and insert password as well
driver.find_element_by_id("login_password").send_keys(password)
# click login button
#driver.find_element_by_name("submit").click()
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("button[id='submit_login']").click()
# wait the ready state to be complete
WebDriverWait(driver=driver, timeout=10).until(
    lambda x: x.execute_script("return document.readyState === 'complete'")
)
error_message = "Incorrect username or password."
# get the errors (if there are)
errors = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("flash-error")
# print the errors optionally
# for e in errors:
#     print(e.text)
# if we find that error message within errors, then login is failed
if any(error_message in e.text for e in errors):
    print("[!] Login failed")
else:
    print("[+] Login successful")
wait.until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.fn-close-popup.popup-actions"))).click()



#web scraping  
    import time
    url = "https://live-cosmos.finq.com/trading-platform/#trading/Shares/Global/USA/All/FACEBOOK"
    driver.get(url)
    time.sleep(3)
    data = driver.page_source
    soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html5lib')
    df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["Instrument", "Sell", "Buy", "Change"])
    for row in soup.find_all('tbody')[0].find_all('tr'):
        col = row.find_all("td")
        Instrument = col[0].text
        Sell = col[1].text
        Buy = col[2].text
        Change = col[3].text
        df = df.append({"Instrument":Instrument,"Sell":Sell,"Buy":Buy,"Change":Change}, ignore_index=True)
    print(df)
```

I have changed the above code as below. Then it returns

```
import time
url = "https://live-cosmos.finq.com/trading-platform/#trading/Shares/Global/USA/All/FACEBOOK"
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(3)
data = driver.page_source
soup = BeautifulSoup(data, 'html5lib')
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=["Instrument", "Sell", "Buy", "Change"])
for row in soup.find_all('tr'):
    col = row.find_all("td")
    Instrument = col[1].text
    Sell = col[2].text
    Buy = col[3].text
    Change = col[4].text
    df = df.append({"Instrument":Instrument,"Sell":Sell,"Buy":Buy,"Change":Change})#, ignore_index=True)
print(df)
```

then it returns

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Instrument, Sell, Buy, Change]
Index: []
```

Comment: Where exactly does it fail and what does the error message say?

Comment: What line gives `List out of index` error?

Comment: @StyleZ, this is the error message i get. IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-413ad3eac488> in <module>
      8 for row in soup.find_all('tbody')[0].find_all('tr'):
      9     col = row.find_all("td")
---> 10     Instrument = col[0].text
     11     Sell = col[1].text
     12     Buy = col[2].text

IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: @Prophet, the above is the message I get on this web scraping..ndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-413ad3eac488> in <module>
      8 for row in soup.find_all('tbody')[0].find_all('tr'):
      9     col = row.find_all("td")
---> 10     Instrument = col[0].text
     11     Sell = col[1].text
     12     Buy = col[2].text

IndexError: list index out of range